# How to convert a column matrix to a row matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

In Matlab, I want to convert a column matrix to a row matrix like this:

```
A =
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
  7
  8
  9
```

To this:

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

How is this done?

Comment: It is amazing how many duplicate questions exist for this ones. Users are just too lazy to search SO, or read the basic documentation...

Comment: @searcoding the question you linked refers to flattening a matrix, although the answers involve transposing I wouldn't call the questions duplicates

Comment: @searcoding, I've reading the question you linked before posting my question. But that one wasn't the answer of mine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want the transpose of the matrix, which in Matlab is written as `A'`.

Comment: If you had just posted `A'` you could have quite possibly had the shortest answer in stackoverflow history.

Comment: Thanks, I felt a little dumb, when I saw the answer, saying, yeah! How I couldn't think that.

Comment: Actually, that performs a conjugate transpose (which leads, in many cases, to the same result). The correct shorthand notation of the transpose function is `A.'`.